# What is the analog to game theory for single-player games?

Tags: game-theory, card-games

Game theory is "the study of mathematical models of conflict and cooperation between intelligent rational decision-makers" (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory)). By this definition, as I understand it, any game studied requires at least 2 participants.

But say we want to study strategies for what the layman might call a single-player game, with imperfect or secret information, such as a solitaire card game. Under what field or name would such a thing be studied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Economists call the one-player analogue of game theory [decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory).

Indeed, before game theory was a standard part of the economist's toolkit, it was sometimes called "multiperson decision theory".

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the other opponent in this case is "nature" or some other system that does not have a capability to choose responses to your actions. This falls under the domain of decision analysis. [Here's a paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1a4c/484d0a3e529457a6ea8075dd6ff124f356b2.pdf) that explores this idea.